# How to use an struct inside a struct

Tags: c, struct

Today my programming teacher given us a challenge to resolve.

We have two structs but each one is using the another struct like this:

```
typedef struct nodeA {
    int data;
    NODE_B *node_b;
    struct nodeA *next;
} NODE_A;

typedef struct nodeB {
    int data;
    NODE_A *node_A;
    struct nodeB *next;
} NODE_B;
```

Of course the order of de declarations every time give a "NODE_X type non-declared" error.

Is there any way for resolve this?

I don't know if exists the prototype for structs like:

```
typedef struct NODE_A;
```

Comment: use `struct nodeB` instead of `NODE_B` ...

Comment: Your title is completely missleading. You don't use a `struct` inside a `struct`, but a **pointer to** `struct`. Learn about the difference, it is vital.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is probably easiest to forward declare both `typedef`s:

```
typedef struct nodeA NODE_A;
typedef struct nodeB NODE_B;

struct nodeA {
    int data;
    NODE_B *node_b;
    NODE_A *next;
};

struct nodeB {
    int data;
    NODE_A *node_A;
    NODE_B *next;
};
```

Comment: @Vega mark the answer as correct if it resolved your issue.